# How to inject Date values by application.properties

Tags: java, spring-boot

Is there a way to inject Date values by application.properties in Spring-Boot projects.
Like this.

```
@Component
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "foo")
public Class FooConfiguration {
    private Date startTime;
    //getter and setter
}
foo.startTime="2019-03-18 00:00:00"
```

Comment: I'm not sure .Are you looking for @Value annotation ?

Comment: @soorapadman `@Value` can only inject a String/Number.

Comment: You should parse to date still it is possible

Comment: Trys something like this `@Value(“#{new java.text.SimpleDateFormat(‘${aDateFormat}’).parse(‘${startTime}’)}”)`

Comment: `@Value` can inject whatever there is a `Converter` for it isn't limited to just `String` and numbers.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can configure a custom converter for configuration properties class like follow:

**DateConverter.java**

```java
@Component
@ConfigurationPropertiesBinding
public class DateConverter implements Converter<String, Date> {
    @Override
    public Date convert(String source) {
        if (source == null) {
            return null;
        }
        return new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss").parse(source);
    }
}
```

**application.properties**

```
foo.start-time=2019-03-18 00:00:00
```

Comment: Not working with spring-boot `2.7.0`

Comment: It works with `2.7.13`

Comment: Doesn't work in springboot 3.1.3